# $\lim x_n=x$ in $X$ satisfies $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of topologic spaces, show that if $f$ is continuos then all series of points $\lim x_n=x$ in $X$ satisfies  $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$

*Atemmpt:*

Let $U$ be a open set in $Y$ such that $f(x)\subset U$, as $f$ continuos then the origin of $U$ denoted by $V$ is open set too,

How can I prove that?

Comment: If by origin you mean preimage, then this is the definition of being continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $f(x)$ in open $V$. Then, since $x$ in open $U = f^{-1}(V)$, $x_n$ is eventually in $U$ and consequently $f(x_n)$ is eventually in $f(U)$.
As $f(U) \subset V$, $f(x_n)$ is eventually in $V$.